# How to display FacesContext message using selectManyListBox

Tags: java, jsf

I am new to JSF. I trying to display a message using the FacesContext message when a item is list box is clicked. In this case, I am trying to display a message when the rendered listbox is empty.

I have tried to put "update" attribute in the selectManyListbox, but it is not working.

part of the xhtml code:

```
    <h:outputLabel value="Category" />
        <h:selectManyListbox   id="x1CategorySelectOneMenu" value="#{x1.selectedCategories}" valueChangeListener="#{x1n.categoryChanged2}" required="true" requiredMessage="Category is required" size="10">
            <f:selectItems value="#{x1.categories}" var="category" itemLabel="#{category}" itemValue="#{category}"/>
            <f:ajax event="valueChange" render="x1SelectOneMenu"/>
            <f:ajax event="valueChange" listener="#{x1.categoryChanged2}" render="msgs" execute="@this"/>  
            <!-- f:ajax render="msgs" / -->
        </h:selectManyListbox>
    <p:messages id="msgs" showDetail="true"/>

   <h:outputLabel id="x1IdLabel" value="Machine" />
        <h:selectManyListbox   id="x1SelectOneMenu" immediate="true" value="#{x1.selectedResources}" required="true" requiredMessage="Machine is required" size="10" >
            <f:selectItems value="#{x1.strResourceIdList}" var="machine" itemLabel="#{strResourceIdList}" itemValue="#{strResourceIdList}" />
        </h:selectManyListbox>
```

part of the Java code:

```
  public void categoryChanged2(ValueChangeEvent event) throws Throwable {
     if(strResourceIdList.isEmpty())
     {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Info","There is no Resource available in this Category"));
         return;
     }
  }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error for so long, the part that make it work is the xhtml part

```
<h:outputLabel value="Category" />
<h:selectManyListbox   id="x1CategorySelectOneMenu" value="#{x1.selectedCategories}" valueChangeListener="#{x1.categoryChanged2}" required="true" requiredMessage="Category is required" size="10">
       <f:selectItems value="#{x1.categories}" var="category" itemLabel="#{category}" itemValue="#{category}"/>
       <f:ajax event="valueChange" render="x1SelectOneMenu msgs"/> 
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

The code `render="x1SelectOneMenu msgs"` is the critical part that make it work for my case. The `x1SelectOneMenu` is the Id for rendered `selectManyListbox` and the `msgs` is the id for `p:messages` id. The separator for JSF is the space.